# JS dejó de funcionar después de borrar cache de Drupal

Tags: javascript, cache, drupal

Tengo una página hecha en Drupal a la que le tuve que hacer unos cambios, como no se veían reflejados en la página, decidí borrar el cache en:

```
Configuration > Performance > Clear Cache
```

El problema es que después de hacer esto todo el JavaScript dejó de funcionar, ¿alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este problema?, es urgente ya que la página perdió funcionalidad. :(

Comment: Control + F5 en el navegador

Comment: No tiene nada que ver con el navegador, algo se movió en el servidor despúes de ejecutar esa acción en Drupal

Comment: ejecuta un cron